# test whether default argument is used or is modified in function call in R

Tags: r, function, arguments, logic

Quick question. I am writing some complex functions in R, and I had a situation come up where I have several function defaults that I want to use (e.g., nA = 5, nB = 5, nPos = 4, nNeg = 4). These defaults are built into the function so I don't have to specify them unless I want to modify them. However, is there anyway to do some logic within the function to see if they were mentioned?

For example, say a user specifies only (nA=3 and nB=5) ... is there a way I can grab the number 8 from that since they were explicitly referenced by the user in the function call (as opposed to relying on the defaults?).

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You use the variables inside your function, if the user does not specify them, they will get the default value. So what is it exactly what you need in addition to that?

Comment: These are all helpful. I am aware that the defaults are set when they are not specified. What I am wanting is to tell if a user, in the function call, explicitly specified an argument rather than relying on the default. In other words, is there any way for a function to tell whether an argument was specified in the call rather than relying on the default? (hint: one solution could be to see if the values ARE at the default, but I was hoping for a logical test to see if they were mentioned at all in the call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`missing()`?

```
> f = function(a=1, b=2, c=3) missing(b)
> f(1, c=3)
[1] TRUE
> f(1, 3)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Just beware: as at `?missing` , "missing(x) is only reliable if x has not been altered since entering the function"

Answer (score 0):

```
f <- function(a=2, b=3) {
  "b" %in% names(as.list(match.call()))
}

f()
#[1] FALSE
f(b=1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Roland's answer is more precise, but perhaps all you are looking for is

```
function(a=5) if( a !=5 ) print('hey, you changed a!')
```